# How to setDrawCircles() for only one (maximum) value in the chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [mpandroidchart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/) and I want to draw a circle only for one Entry in the LineDataSet but not the rest. I have tried to accomplish it using two LineDataSets but it hasn't worked so far. Here's my code:

```
LineDataSet scoreDataSet = new LineDataSet(values, "Score");
scoreDataSet.setDrawCircles(false);

// Entry with max value is the last one
Entry circleEntry = scoreDataSet.getEntryForXIndex(scoreDataSet.getEntryCount()-1);

LineDataSet circularDataSet = new LineDataSet(values, "Score");
circularDataSet.setDrawCircles(true);
int size = circularDataSet.getEntryCount()-1;
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if (i != circleEntry.getXIndex()) {
            circularDataSet.removeEntry(circularDataSet.getEntryForXIndex(i));
    }
}
.
.
.
ArrayList<LineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<LineDataSet>();
dataSets.add(scoreDataSet);
dataSets.add(circularDataSet);
```

This just prints a dot(circularDataSet) and not the scoreDataSet. I was expecting it to merge both the DataSets so as to mark the highest value with a circle and drawing the rest as a line chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks good in general, there are just a few flaws.

Don't create the "circularDataSet" and initialize it with the same values like the "scoreDataSet" and then remove all except one.

What you should do instead is **find the largest entry** in your "scoreDataSet", and then only add this single entry to the "circularDataSet".

Comment: I see what you mean. There was a minor hitch. Fixed it . Thanks!